# Using a Content ID Contextual Filter in a Views Block in Drupal 8

Tags: view, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I am attempting to create a View that, instead of showing a list of all nodes of a content type, will show only a single node of a content type based on node ID. In Drupal 7, I worked almost exclusively in Views Content Panes and was able to achieve this based on NID and then setting the Argument Input to From Context: Content ID. How do I get similar results using Blocks in Drupal 8?

I have a view that is correctly configured to show all nodes of a content type. I've tried to add a Contextual Filter: ID; but I cannot figure out how to configure it to get a result that isn't All Results.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit the contextual filter Content ID, you  have :

**`WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE`** (base view is built without filter, this is the case)

Check `Provide default value` to set how filter values should be retrieved, then you can choose a type, for example *Content ID from URL*, or *Query parameter*, etc.

For example with *Query parameter* you can set the parameter name and the *Fallback value*. In your case you would set something like `nid` as the query param, and `all` or a fixed node ID as fallback value ('all' is the exception value by default that is to disable the filter).

Given this example, you 'd just add the query `?nid=5` to the request path. It seems you need the block filtered by default though, in this case just set a fixed node ID (eg. `5` instead of `all`) as fallback value in views admin, then the block will be filtered by default the same way.

Comment: Thank you! I've set my Contextual Filter as you've suggested, but the block is still returning all results. I've placed the block in a page I've created (/test-page). Do I need to change the URL to include the nid in order for this to work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Shannon If you set the type to "query parameter" using `nid` like in the example above, you would enable contextual filtering just by adding the query `?nid=5` to the request path. Now in views admin if you set a fixed node ID (`5` instead of `all`)  as fallback value, the block will be filtered by default exactly the same way.